# How to clearly separate front-end and back-end logic

Tags: javascript, php, session

I followed some online tutorials about logging forms but they are too simple in my opinion. What I mean is that they always send the username and password to the same PHP page, which does both authentication and displaying result.

I just wonder if it is possible to separate the logic of front-end and back-end. Front-end is only responsible for sending and receiving request while back-end does database connection and authentication. Back-end should send result back to front-end which display them accordingly.

I have to confess that I am newbie in web development and I really don't know if this is the correct direction at all thus seek your professional help.

Below is my design,

Front-end has a button which calls javascript function for sending and receiving request.

```
<button type="button" onclick="javascript:queryLogin()">
```

Javascript functions prepare post request and receiving response.

```
    function queryLogin() {
        var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
        var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var parameters = "username="+username+"&"+"password="+password;

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                statusLogin(xmlhttp.responseText);
            }
        }

        xmlhttp.open(/*method=*/"POST", /*url=*/"login_back.php", /*async=*/true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.send(parameters);
    }

    function statusLogin(response) {
        var arr = JSON.parse(response);

        switch(arr.result) {
            case 0:   document.getElementById("message").innerHTML="";
                      break;
            default:  document.getElementById("message").innerHTML="";
                      /* TODO: How to destroy session? */
                      break;
        }
    }
```

So basically I am stuck in this scenario: If authentication fails, front-end should destroy session but now the logic is in javascript which is difficult to destroy a php session.

Please advise what to do. Thanks in advance.

Comment: think the single most important thing you could do to separate front end and back end is to just use a framework. Just about all the frameworks abstract requests and responses making it easier to seperate front end and back end concerns.

Comment: Two small advices, use a JS framework for basic tasks. JQuery is a very simple library especially for AJAX requests. Keep any sensitive logic in the backend, which means your session management. The login_back.php should do the login AND manage the session accordingly. It should then only return the status of the operation.

Comment: While traditionally I'd agree on using frameworks, I think it's actually important to avoid frameworks when first learning the ropes. To many people never learn how to actually use their chosen language and rather only learn how to use some framework. However, when it comes time to build something real, then yes, definitely use a framework for that.

Answer (score 3):

What you're talking about is essentially what's referred to as a SPA, or Single Page Application. In this type of site, the application logic is shifted almost entirely from the server to the client, which provides the benefit of allowing you to have an extremely thin server setup. Traditionally, you'll see sites like these use Node.js on the server-side because there's so little work to be done there, but you could really use any data source, be it a Web API or a full stack web application.

However, SPAs are pretty complex. Coordinating all the work on the client-side is not for the faint of heart, since none of the components of the web are really intended for that. Here, client-side frameworks such as Angular/Backbone/etc. are almost a necessity, as rolling your own is not only wasteful of your time and resources, but will likely never be as good as what the community has developed. While SPAs can be fun to toy around with when learning web development, they're a very poor way to get your feet wet. Until you have some experience under your belt, I'd recommend going a traditional server-side route and not worrying about stuff like this, yet.

A server-side focused web application can be just as a performant as client-side, if not more, and will introduce you to concepts of working with a server that would likely be glossed over by jumping right into a client-side MVC/MVVM framework.